(NOBRIDGE) ERROR: Failed to create a new MMKV instance with react-native-mmkv in Expo project
I am encountering the following error when trying to use react-native-mmkv in my React Native project:
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error: Failed to create a new MMKV instance: The native MMKV Module could not be found.
* Make sure react-native-mmkv is correctly autolinked (run `npx react-native config` to verify)
* Make sure you enabled the new architecture (TurboModules) and CodeGen properly generated the react-native-mmkv specs. See https://github.com/reactwg/react-native-new-architecture/blob/main/docs/enable-apps.md
* Make sure you are using react-native 0.74.0 or higher, because react-native-mmkv is a C++ TurboModule.

Versions:
{
  "react-native": "0.76.5",
  "expo": "~52.0.18",
  "react-native-mmkv": "^3.1.0"
}

Steps I've Taken:

Enabled the New Architecture in my project.
Verified I’m using react-native version 0.76.5, which supports
TurboModules.
Cleaned and rebuilt my project with npx expo prebuild --clean.

How can I resolve this error and ensure react-native-mmkv works properly in my Expo project with the New Architecture enabled?
